# Hide button on UIWebView when Internet is available

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an iOS 7 app with a `UIWebView`.

When there is no Internet connection I want to add a picture to the web view, along with some text ("No Internet connection") as well as a button for refreshing the page.

I can add the button alright, but it is not hidden when the Internet connection is on. I want to hide button text and picture when the device has Internet and hide them when there is no Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Reachability to track changes between offline/online (https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability).

```
// Allocate a reachability object
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

// Set the blocks 
reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reach)
{
    // Hide button
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reach)
{
    // Show button
};

// Start the notifier, which will cause the reachability object to retain itself!
[reach startNotifier];
```